# Python: Resgatar texto html mysql

Tags: html, mysql, python

Estou utilizando Bottle.py para estudo e testes... Estou com um problema no resgate de uma informação do banco de dados. A tabela está assim:

```
create table if not exists postagens (
    idPostagem INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    tituloPostagem VARCHAR(100),
    assunto varchar(100),
    conteudoPostagem TEXT,
    imgPath VARCHAR(255),
    dataRegistro DATETIME
);
```

Aqui está meu registro no banco.

```
('1', 'teste', 'lop', '<p>testando testando<em> testando testando testando testando</em></p>\r\n<p style=\"text-align: right;\"><strong>testando testando testando testando testando testando</strong></p>', '18010004_1268615233256136_1367753241579175253_n.jpg', '2018-01-28 01:02:43')
```

Aqui o método com select no arquivo adm.py as manager:
obs: select * from **** porque é para testar apenas.

```
def view_publicacoes(nomePostagem):
    cursor.execute("select * from postagens;")
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

Aqui o método da rota

```
@app.route("/postagens/<nomePostagem>")
def view_publicacoes(nomePostagem):
    a = manager.view_publicacoes(nomePostagem)
    return template('./html/teste.tpl', lbImg=a[0][4], lbTituloPost=a[0][1], lbData=a[0][5], lbContent=a[0][3])
```

Ele trás o texto, mas não estiliza ele como deveria no html, e quando inspeciono o elemento onde se localiza o texto ele me mostra como se fosse uma string.

> <p>testando testando<em> testando testando testando testando</em></p>
>   <p style="text-align: right;"><strong>testando testando testando testando testando testando</strong></p>

Já codifiquei para unicode, para str, converti para byte e decodifiquei na apresentação, tentei usar BLOB no lugar do text... E a unica coisa que pude notar é isto só acontece com textos grandes... aguardo resposta.

Comment: Consegui resolver colocando ! na view.

Comment: Então há 2 opções: excluir a pergunta caso ache que não será útil no futuro ou postar uma resposta (recomendável) explicando como resolveu pra caso alguém possa ter o mesmo problema conseguir resolver.